# How to set header in all responses in Play! framework 2.7 (Java)

Tags: playframework, play-framework-2.7

In older Play! versions (like 2.3) it was possible to modify the header of all responses like

```
public class WithMyPHeaderAction extends Action<WithMyPHeader> {

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> call(Context ctx) {
        ctx.response().setHeader("any", "value");
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

How do I do this with Play! 2.7 without deprecation (ctx.response() is deprecated since 2.7), in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an Action to do this. In the controller you can just:

```
return ok().withHeader("any", "value");
```

If you have to do this in an Action same thing:

```
@Override
public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Request req) {
    return delegate.call(req).thenApply(r -> r.withHeader("any", "value"));
}
```

I'm using `play.mvc.Action.Simple` for the Action. Also I've tested this on Play 2.8.1, should work on Play 2.7 too.

Comment: I don't want to add withHeader("any", "value") to all my controller results, but the Action example is exactly what I was looking for, thx!